# How to print remainder of a division using the library emu8086.inc

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-division, emu8086

I am trying to print the remainder of division using emu8086.inc library but the remainder shows ascii value when I run the program. What should I write to print the remainder exactly?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA

.CODE
MAIN PROC

INCLUDE 'emu8086.inc'

 DEFINE_SCAN_NUM   ;DEFINE NUMBER FOR SCAN

 DEFINE_PRINT_NUM  ;DFINE NUMBER TO PRINT  



 DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS ;DEFINE UNSIGNED NUMBER TO PRINT

 CALL SCAN_NUM   ;FIRST INPUT
 MOV AX,CX       ;SHIFT THE DATA TO AX

 PUTC 0AH        ;NEW LINE
 PUTC 0DH

                 ;SECOND INPUT
CALL SCAN_NUM
                 ;AX/CX = AX
 IDIV CX
                 ;NEW LINE
 PRINTN ''

 CALL PRINT_NUM  ;PRINT QUOTIENT 
 MOV AH,2
 MOV DL,AL
 INT 21H
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ;SECOND INPUT
> CALL SCAN_NUM
>              ;AX/CX = AX
> IDIV CX
> ```

The comment is wrong! `IDIV CX` will do a signed divide of `DX:AX` by `CX`.
You still need to setup `DX`.

`CWD` is an instruction that will sign-extend the `AX` register into `DX:AX`. If `AX` is positive then `DX` will get 0, and if `AX` is negative then `DX` will get -1. This step is necesssary for the `IDIV CX` instruction to work correctly! It will return the quotient in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`.

```
;SECOND INPUT
CALL SCAN_NUM      ;CX has the second input
CWD                ;AX has the first input, sign extending it to DX:AX
IDIV CX            ;DX:AX / CX
```

---

> ```
> CALL PRINT_NUM  ;PRINT QUOTIENT
> ```

This does print the quotient from `AX`. The remainder from the division is in `DX`. Just move it to `AX` and invoke the same print macro procedure for printing signed numbers.

```
CALL PRINT_NUM  ;PRINT QUOTIENT
mov  ax, dx
CALL PRINT_NUM  ;PRINT REMAINDER
```

---

> ```
> MOV AH,2
> MOV DL,AL
> INT 21H
> ```

This code doesn't do anything useful in your program.